# Is this a safe version of double-checked locking?

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic, locking, atomic

Slightly modified version of canonical broken double-checked locking from Wikipedia:

```
class Foo {
    private Helper helper = null;
    public Helper getHelper() {
        if (helper == null) {
            synchronized(this) {
                if (helper == null) {

                    // Create new Helper instance and store reference on
                    // stack so other threads can't see it.
                    Helper myHelper = new Helper();

                    // Atomically publish this instance.
                    atomicSet(helper, myHelper);
                }
            }
        }
        return helper;
    }
}
```

Does simply making the publishing of the newly created Helper instance atomic make this double checked locking idiom safe, assuming that the underlying atomic ops library works properly?  I realize that in Java, one could just use `volatile`, but even though the example is in pseudo-Java, this is supposed to be a language-agnostic question.

**See also:**

[Double checked locking Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157198/double-checked-locking-article)

Comment: why isn't the synchronized block enough yo make it thread safe?

Comment: @Ido: See http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.htmlfor one example.

Comment: That link should be http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html (the for was included)

Answer (score 14):

It entirely depends on the *exact* memory model of your platform/language.

My rule of thumb: *just don't do it*. Lock-free (or reduced lock, in this case) programming is *hard* and shouldn't be attempted unless you're a threading ninja. You should only even *contemplate* it when you've got profiling proof that you really need it, and in that case you get the absolute best and most recent book on threading for *that particular platform* and see if it can help you.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can answer the question in a language-agnostic fashion without getting away from code completely. It all depends on how `synchronized` and `atomicSet` work in your pseudocode.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is language dependent - it comes down to the guarantees provided by `atomicSet()`.

If the construction of myHelper can be spread out after the `atomicSet()` then it doesn't matter how the variable is assigned to the shared state.

i.e.

```
// Create new Helper instance and store reference on
// stack so other threads can't see it.
Helper myHelper = new Helper(); // ALLOCATE MEMORY HERE BUT DON'T INITIALISE

// Atomically publish this instance.
atomicSet(helper, myHelper); // ATOMICALLY POINT UNINITIALISED MEMORY from helper

// other thread gets run at this time and tries to use helper object 

// AT THE PROGRAMS LEISURE INITIALISE Helper object.
```

If this is allowed by the language then the double checking will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Using volatile would not prevent a multiple instantiations - however using the synchronize will prevent multiple instances being created. However with your code it is possible that helper is returned before it has been setup (thread 'A' instantiates it, but before it is setup thread 'B' comes along, helper is non-null and so returns it straight away. To fix that problem, remove the first if (helper == null).

Comment: Take a closer look.  'new Helper' is being assigned to a stack variable, not the member variable.  The atomicSet (assuming it works) prevents the race condition you are pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is broken, because the problem of a partially constructed object is not addressed.

Answer (score 0):

**To all the people worried about a partially constructed object:**

As far as I understand, the problem of partially constructed objects is *only* a problem within constructors.  In other words, within a constructor, if an object references itself (including it's subclass) or it's members, then there are possible issues with partial construction.  Otherwise, when a constructor returns, the class is fully constructed.

I think you are confusing partial construction with the different problem of how the compiler optimizes the writes.  The compiler can choose to A) allocate the memory for the new Helper object, B) write the address to myHelper (the local stack variable), and then C) invoke any constructor initialization.  Anytime after point B and before point C, accessing myHelper would be a problem.

It is this compiler optimization of the writes, not partial construction that the cited papers are concerned with.  In the original single-check lock solution, optimized writes can allow multiple threads to see the member variable between points B and C.  This implementation avoids the write optimization issue by using a local stack variable.

The main scope of the cited papers is to describe the various problems with the double-check lock solution.  However, unless the atomicSet method is also synchronizing against the Foo class, this solution is not a double-check lock solution.  It is using multiple locks.

I would say this all comes down to the implementation of the atomic assignment function.  The function needs to be truly atomic, it needs to guarantee that processor local memory caches are synchronized, and it needs to do all this at a lower cost than simply always synchronizing the getHelper method.

Based on the cited paper, in Java, it is unlikely to meet all these requirements.  Also, something that should be very clear from the paper is that Java's memory model changes frequently.  It adapts as better understanding of caching, garbage collection, etc. evolve, as well as adapting to changes in the underlying real processor architecture that the VM runs on.

As a rule of thumb, if you optimize your Java code in a way that depends on the underlying implementation, as opposed to the API, you run the risk of having broken code in the next release of the JVM.  (Although, sometimes you will have no choice.)

---

**dsimcha:**

If your atomicSet method is real, then I would try sending your question to Doug Lea (along with your atomicSet implementation).  I have a feeling he's the kind of guy that would answer.  I'm guessing that for Java he will tell you that it's cheaper to always synchronize and to look to optimize somewhere else.